# Not asked for Partition when i installed ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, system-installation

i installed ubuntu 12.04 lts version in my computer, i had  installed ubuntu successfully, but during installation it was not asking for any partition, will it be problem?

what space it will take in my hard disk, how to check, where my installed package will sit?
how to check that too?

Sorry for asking two many questions, but i need to know these things,

your answers will  be more helpful to me

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu as the only operating system on the machine or is it alongside something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose Manual Setting while installation. There you can give partition sizes.

You can go through the below link for different partition schemes:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

To check the partitions & their sizes you can issue below command:

sudo fdisk -l

If you meant where package executables reside. Check below mentioned directories:

/usr/bin & /usr/sbin

For more information on Ubuntu directory structure refer:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview